# Move files in a directory to another directory

Tags: batch-file

for a updater application I need a small batch script:

```
move %temp%\MyApp_update\*.* "%1" /Y
```

In this case, `"%temp%\MyApp_update\"` exists with subdirs and the argument "%1" was also a valid path in my tests.

According to some websites this syntax should be correct (e.g. https://www.maketecheasier.com/move-files-by-type-in-windows/). But my Output:

```
Syntaxfehler.
```

(It's german - it means "snytax error" in english)

What is the error in my batch file?

Comment: What does your command look like when the parameter is filled in?

Comment: @Dominique `move  /Y C:\Users\pietr\AppData\Local\Temp\MyApp_update\*.* "C:\Users\pietr\OneDrive\C++\test"`

Comment: Add a backslash at your destination: most probably your PC doesn't know if "test" is a file or a directory.

Comment: Well, it works if I move the directory (`[...]\MyApp_update\`) to the other one. So the second path is not the problem, I want to move all *Files* from the directory, but not the directory.

Comment: Quote both source and destination paths and replace `%1` by `%~1`…